# How to fix, 'flutter doctor' for intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

'flutter doctor' error.

Search issue, or other persons same issue.
Also re-installed and re-started IntelliJ and re-booted os system.
Again, again, again...

Please show the bellow image...

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the intellij?

Comment: Like @NhaPhạmThị said, I think restarting your intellij-idea should work

Comment: what error did you face namely? I'd suggest reporting the issue to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: Of course, I tried restarted 'IntelliJ-IDE' again. But there is the same error.
@lena Thank you.

Comment: I writed issue to github, fluttet/flutter. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36414